# Element Class test showing ng-untouched and failing with proper input

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to test a little angular app I have made.[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wYba.png) is just a simple table of users(you can add and edit users). Name and email input are validated.

I want to test validation on name input, the validation is quite simple - your name must be at least than 3 characters long. If your name passes the validation [the name input will be in green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJWKS.png) and class of the input will be

> username form-control input-sm ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-valid-required ng-valid ng-valid-minlength

if your name doesn't pass the validation [the name input will be in yellow color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7Feu.png) and class of the input will be

> username form-control input-sm ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-touched

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
onPrepare : function() {
    // browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
},
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['specs/main-spec.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000,
},
};
```

main-spec.js

```
const userFormPage = require('../pages/user-form-page');
describe('test app', function () {
    it('should get to the main page of the app', function () {
        browser.get('http://localhost:8080/TestAppExample/index');
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('http://localhost:8080/TestAppExample/index');
    });
    it('should write wrong input in the name input',function () {
        userFormPage.sendKeysNameInput('na');
        expect(userFormPage.getNameInput().getAttribute('value')).toEqual('na');
        // browser.wait(function () {
        //     return nameInput.getAttribute('class').then((attr) => {
        //         return attr == 'username form-control input-sm ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-touched';
        //     })
        // },10000);
        expect(userFormPage.getNameInput().getAttribute('class')).toEqual('username form-control input-sm ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-touched');
    });
});
```

user-form-page.js

```
var userFormPage= function () {
    var nameInput = element(by.id('uname'));

    this.getNameInput = function () {
        return nameInput;
    };

    this.sendKeysNameInput = function (keys) {
        nameInput.clear().sendKeys(keys)
    }
};

module.exports = new userFormPage();
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test App</title>
        <link href="/TestAppExample/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/TestAppExample/static/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-ng-app="myApp" class="ng-cloak">
        <div class="generic-container" data-ng-controller="UserController as controller">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">User Registration Form </span></div>
                <div class="formcontainer">
                    <form data-ng-submit="controller.submit()" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">
                        <input type="hidden" data-ng-model="controller.user.id" />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="uname">Name</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="controller.user.userName" id="uname" class="username form-control input-sm"
                                        placeholder="Enter your name" required data-ng-minlength="3"/>
                                    <div class="has-error" data-ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
                                        <span data-ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.required">This is a required field</span>
                                        <span data-ng-show="myForm.uname.$error.minlength">Minimum length required is 3</span>
                                        <span data-ng-show="myForm.uname.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
                                     </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="address">Address</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input type="text" data-ng-model="controller.user.address" id="address" class="form-control input-sm"
                                        placeholder="Enter your Address. [This field is validation free]"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                <label class="col-md-2 control-lable" for="email">Email</label>
                                <div class="col-md-7">
                                    <input type="email" data-ng-model="controller.user.email" id="email" class="email form-control input-sm"
                                        placeholder="Enter your Email" required/>
                                    <div class="has-error" data-ng-show="myForm.$dirty">
                                        <span data-ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">This is a required field</span>
                                        <span data-ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid">This field is invalid </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-actions floatRight">
                                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="{{!controller.user.id ? 'Add' : 'Update'}}"
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
                                <button type="button" id="reset" data-ng-click="controller.reset()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                    data-ng-disabled="myForm.$pristine">Reset Form</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of Users </span></div>
                <div class="tablecontainer">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th width="20%"></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="u in controller.users" class="user-row">
                                <td><span data-ng-bind="u.userName" class="user-name-td"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-ng-bind="u.address"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-ng-bind="u.email"></span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" id="edit" data-ng-click="controller.edit(u.id)"
                                        class="btn btn-success custom-width">Edit</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="remove" data-ng-click="controller.openModal(u)"
                                        class="btn btn-danger custom-width">Remove</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-ng-controller="ModalInstanceController as modalCtrl">
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContent">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Delete user</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label class="control-lable">Are you sure wan't to delete user {{userName}}?</label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="ok" type="button" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" type="button" ng-click="$dismiss('cancel')">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>

        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/service/UserService.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/controller/UserController.js"></script>
        <script src="/TestAppExample/static/js/controller/ModalInstanceController.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My test writes 'na' in the name input and the name input becomes yellow as it should,but when I run my test I get the following error

> Expected 'username form-control input-sm ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength' to equal 'username form-control input-sm ng-invalid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-required ng-invalid-minlength ng-touched'.

**EDIT**

If I change my `sendKeysNameInput()` method to that

```
 this.sendKeysNameInput = function (id, keys) {
    var targetInput = element(by.id(id));
    (<HTMLInputElement>targetInput).focus().clear().sendKeys(keys)
}
```

Then I get the unexpected token error

```
        (<HTMLInputElement>targetInput).focus().clear().sendKeys(keys)
         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

My idea(WebStorm) suggested to me to set my language as react when I changed my `sendKeysNameInput()` method, but I am using plain js with node.js(protractor and jasmine libraries) and testing an Angular app.

Comment: You are not guaranteed that you will get the html class attributes in the same order. "form-control input-sm" is the same as "input-sm form-control"

Answer (score 0):

Add `nameInput.focus()` into your `sendKeysNameInput()` which will set focus to your input and cause it to be considered "touched". Alternatively you could change the `sendKeysNameInput()` to something like

```
this.sendKeysNameInput = function (id, keys) {
    var targetInput = element(by.id(id));
    (<HTMLInputElement>targetInput).focus().clear().sendKeys(keys)
}
```

And `getNameInput()` to something more like

```
this.getInputValue = function (id) {
  return (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(id)).value
};
```

And make a method called `getClassValue()`

```
this.getInputValue = function (id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).className
};
```

Which would allow you to do this

```
userFormPage.sendKeysNameInput('uname', 'na');
expect(userFormPage.getInputValue('uname').toEqual('na');
expect(userFormPage.getClassValue('uname').toEqual('...');
```

And that would turn your functions into [pure functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976) instead, allowing you to work with multiple inputs in the form as it grows.

Another thing to mention is that, if I am right, you **do not want to get the class attribute** but instead the *className* DOM Property. Attributes are used for the ***initialization*** of DOM Properties and typically do not change afterward, the class attribute *should* get updated but best practice is to grab the DOM Property which will *always* be updated.

Certain properties like `textContent` do not have attributes attached to them, and on the reverse some attributes like `colspan` do not have associated DOM Properties, in the case of `colspan` getting the attribute is the only possible thing to do. In the case of Input which does have a `value` attribute and `value` property, you will find that the attribute never updates which you can see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qvsb3).

Comment: If I change the sendKeysNameInput() method to what you suggested or  add nameInput.focus() into my sendKeysNameInput() method I get the following error
 **Failed: targetInput.focus is not a function**

Comment: Sorry, do you see where getInputValue uses <HTMLInputElement> to cast the element to an Input Element? You need to do the same thing in the sendKeysNameInput. I’m updating my answer to reflect this.